# Bash: How to build a recursive cowsay

Tags: linux, bash

Here's a linux command (you might need the `cowsay` application.

```
cowsay 'moo'
```

Here's another command:

```
cowsay 'moo' | cowsay -n
```

The result is pretty entertaining:

```
 ______________________________
/  _____                       \
| < moo >                      |
|  -----                       |
|         \   ^__^             |
|          \  (oo)\_______     |
|             (__)\       )\/\ |
|                 ||----w |    |
\                 ||     ||    /
 ------------------------------
        \   ^__^
         \  (oo)\_______
            (__)\       )\/\
                ||----w |
                ||     ||
```

Now, of course, it's pretty fun to repeat that piped command N times. It looks a little like this:

```
 cowsay 'moo' | cowsay -n | cowsay -n | cowsay -n | cowsay -n | cowsay -n | cowsay -n | cowsay -n | cowsay -n | cowsay -n | cowsay -n | cowsay -n
```

[image: Cows nested inside cows saying things]

But I'm thinking there must be a neater way of achieving this. Let's just say I want 500 cows all saying each other, or 1,000, or 1,000,000. Surely I don't just have to keep my finger on the paste button?

Here's the question; is there a way in bash (command or script) to recursively pass the output of a command into itself a given number of times?

Answer (score 13):

```
cowsayN() {
    local n=$1
    shift
    if ((n>1)); then
        cowsay -n | cowsayN $((n-1))
    else
        cowsay -n
    fi
}
echo 'moo' | cowsayN 500
```

Comment: when my terminal window spans two 27-inch monitors, I can render `echo 'moo' | cowsayN 95` without line breaks

Comment: @knb most terminal emulators will allow you to shrink text and see more. You might not be able to read the moo, but you’ll see the shape.

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't test it for the moment:

```
output=$(cowsay 'moo')
for ((i=0;i<50;i+=1)); do output=$(cowsay "$output"); done
echo "$output"
```

modified adding <<< to pass value as input

```
output=$(cowsay -n <<<'moo')
for ((i=0;i<50;i+=1)); do output=$(cowsay -n <<<"$output"); done
echo "$output"
```

Comment: I'm currently getting this error. `bash: /usr/games/cowsay: Argument list too long`. Maybe repost this when you've had a chance to test it?

Comment: Then try this: ```for ((i=0;i<50;i+=1)); do cowsay "MOO"; done```

Comment: But this is better: ```for ((i=0;i<${1};i+=1)); do cowsay "${2}"; done``` - And lets say the scriptname is: cowsay.sh - Then execute it like this: ```sh cowsay.sh 10 'Hard to chew'```